# Why isn't the groupby method working in this rolling sum calculation in Pandas and how can I fix it?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data, which I multi-index with Date and Ticker as indices and I am then adding a rolling sum of the Vol column for each stock.

Raw Data:

```
Date,Ticker,SharePrice,Vol
2014-12-31,MSFT,10.79,16.24
2015-03-31,MSFT,19.44,14.94
2015-06-30,MSFT,3.73,19.79
2015-09-30,MSFT,3.76,6.52
2015-12-31,MSFT,10.56,17.91
2016-03-31,MSFT,13.56,11.96
2016-06-30,MSFT,16.27,19.79
2015-03-31,GM,18.22,9.92
2015-06-30,GM,17.16,18.69
2015-09-30,GM,15.92,17.45
```

Here is the code I use to calculate my rolling sum of vol - note that I do not want the rolling sum to include vol related to a different Ticker (I attempt to use gruopby to stop this but it doesn't work):

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

stocks = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\stocks.csv", index_col=["Date", "Ticker"])

stocks['RollingVol'] = stocks['Vol'].groupby(level=1).fillna(0).rolling(1095, min_periods=2).sum()

print(stocks)
```

Here is the result I get:

```
Date,Ticker,SharePrice,Vol,RollingVol
2014-12-31,MSFT,10.79,16.24,
2015-03-31,MSFT,19.44,14.94,31.18
2015-06-30,MSFT,3.73,19.79,50.97
2015-09-30,MSFT,3.76,6.52,57.489999999999995
2015-12-31,MSFT,10.56,17.91,75.39999999999999
2016-03-31,MSFT,13.56,11.96,87.35999999999999
2016-06-30,MSFT,16.27,19.79,107.14999999999998
2015-03-31,GM,18.22,9.92,117.06999999999998
2015-06-30,GM,17.16,18.69,135.76
2015-09-30,GM,15.92,17.45,153.20999999999998
```

My problem for example here is that the first rolling sum entry for GM (117.0699999) is including the MSFT values whereas it should just be NaN (since min_periods = 2) and then the second entry for GM should be 9.92+18.69= 28.61 and so on as detailed below. I don't understand why the groupby(level=1) in my code is not achieving this and how I can fix it?

Many thanks in advance

Expected Result:

```
Date,Ticker,SharePrice,Vol,RollingVol
2014-12-31,MSFT,10.79,16.24,
2015-03-31,MSFT,19.44,14.94,31.18
2015-06-30,MSFT,3.73,19.79,50.97
2015-09-30,MSFT,3.76,6.52,57.49
2015-12-31,MSFT,10.56,17.91,75.4
2016-03-31,MSFT,13.56,11.96,87.36
2016-06-30,MSFT,16.27,19.79,107.15
2015-03-31,GM,18.22,9.92,
2015-06-30,GM,17.16,18.69,28.61
2015-09-30,GM,15.92,17.45,46.06
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that when you call *groupby* then
for each group is invoked actually **only the first function**
from the following content, in your example only *fillna*, which
changes nothing.

Invocation of the following methods is performed on the final
("consolidated") result of the preceding *groupby*.

To compute what you really want, change your code to:

```
stocks['RollingVol'] = stocks.Vol.groupby(level=1).apply(
lambda grp: grp.rolling(1095, min_periods=2).sum())
```

The result, for your sample data, is:

```
                   SharePrice    Vol  RollingVol
Date       Ticker                               
2014-12-31 MSFT         10.79  16.24         NaN
2015-03-31 MSFT         19.44  14.94       31.18
2015-06-30 MSFT          3.73  19.79       50.97
2015-09-30 MSFT          3.76   6.52       57.49
2015-12-31 MSFT         10.56  17.91       75.40
2016-03-31 MSFT         13.56  11.96       87.36
2016-06-30 MSFT         16.27  19.79      107.15
2015-03-31 GM           18.22   9.92         NaN
2015-06-30 GM           17.16  18.69       28.61
2015-09-30 GM           15.92  17.45       46.06
```

Note that the first value in each group is *NaN*, since you want
*min_periods=2*.

And a final detail to consider: You chose a strikingly big window
size (*1095*).
This raises suspicion that you actually want an **expanding** window,
from the start of the current group, up to the current row.
Something like:

```
stocks['RollingVol'] = stocks.Vol.groupby(level=1).apply(
    lambda grp: grp.expanding(min_periods=2).sum())
```

Or maybe you want the rolling sum for 3 years, assuming that you have
data for each day.